# React music player

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I want to create a music player on a website. The Ideea is to choose a song and play it automaticly. The song must play on all pages and I need an play/pause button.
I have created all the componentns but I have a bug. When I'm on the main page with the player component, the play/pause button does not work properly, If I stop the music I can't start it again, it works only on another pages. Here is the website https://thebrandbar.studio/#/

App.js

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { HashRouter as Router, Route, Switch } from "react-router-dom";
import ScrollToTop from "./helper/scrollToTop";

import Home from "./pages/Home";
import Projects from "./pages/Projects";
import Team from "./pages/Team";
import ProjectPage from "./pages/ProjectPage";
import Error from "./pages/Error";
import TermsOfUse from "./pages/TermsOfUse";
import PrivacyPolicy from "./pages/PrivacyPolicy";
import Cookies from "./pages/Cookies";


const App = () => {
    const [currentTrackIndex, setCurrentTrackIndex] = useState(null);
    const [trackURL, setTrackURL] = useState('');
    const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

    const callbackFunction = (currentTrackIndex, trackURL, playing) => {
        setCurrentTrackIndex(currentTrackIndex);
        setTrackURL(trackURL);
        setPlaying(playing);
    };

    const player = document.getElementById('player');
    const onPlayPauseClickHandler = (event) => {
        setPlaying(!playing);
        if (!playing) {
            player.play();
        } else {
            player.pause();
        }
    }
    const renderPlayBtn = () => {
        if (currentTrackIndex == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            return <div className="play-btn">
                <p onClick={onPlayPauseClickHandler} className={`play ${playing ? "red-bg" : "blue-bg"}`}>
                    {playing ? "SOUND OFF" : "SOUND ON"}
                </p>
            </div>
        }
    }

    return (
        <>
            <Router>
                <ScrollToTop />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/'}`} >
                        <Home parentCallback={callbackFunction} player={player}/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route
                        path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/projects'}`}
                        component={Projects}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/project/:projectId`}
                        component={ProjectPage}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/team'}`}
                        component={Team}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/terms'}`}
                        component={TermsOfUse}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/privacy'}`}
                        component={PrivacyPolicy}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/cookies'}`}
                        component={Cookies}
                    />
                    <Route exact component={Error} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
            <audio id="player" src={trackURL} type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
            {
                renderPlayBtn()
            }
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

The main page

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from 'react';
import Loader from "../container/Loader";
import { Helmet } from "react-helmet";
import Cookies from "../components/cookies";
import LayoutDefault from "../container/LayoutDefault";
import Header from "../components/header/Header";
import HeroArea from "../container/Hero";
import MusicPlayer from "../container/MusicPlayer";
import FeaturedProjects from "../container/FeaturedProjects";
import Contact from "../container/Contact";
import Footer from "../container/Footer";

const Home = ({ parentCallback, player }) => {
    const [currentTrackIndex, setCurrentTrackIndex] = useState(null);
    const [trackURL, setTrackURL] = useState('');
    const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

    const callbackFunction = (currentTrackIndex, trackURL, playing) => {
        setCurrentTrackIndex(currentTrackIndex);
        setTrackURL(trackURL);
        setPlaying(playing);
    };

    useEffect(() => {
        parentCallback(currentTrackIndex, trackURL, playing);
    });


    return (
        <Loader>
            <Helmet>
                <title>TheBrandBar</title>
            </Helmet>
            <Cookies />
            <LayoutDefault className="template-color-2 bg_color--4">
                <Header />
                <HeroArea />
                <MusicPlayer parentCallback={callbackFunction} player={player}/>
                <FeaturedProjects />
                <Contact />
                <Footer />
            </LayoutDefault>
        </Loader>
    );
};

export default Home;
```

and Music Player component

```
import React, { useState, useEffect } from "react";
import { Container, Row, Col } from "react-bootstrap";

import DB from '../data/music/music.js';


const Player = ({ parentCallback }) => {

  const [tracksList] = useState(DB);
  const [currentTrackIndex, setCurrentTrackIndex] = useState(null);
  const [trackID, setTrackID] = useState(null);
  const [trackURL, setTrackURL] = useState('');
  const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

  useEffect(() => {
    parentCallback(currentTrackIndex, trackURL, playing);
  });

  const selectThisTrack = (event, trackID) => {
    let currentTrackIndex = 0;
    tracksList.map((track, index) => {
      if (track.id === trackID) {
        currentTrackIndex = index;
      }
      return track;
    });
    setCurrentTrackIndex(currentTrackIndex);
    setTrackID(tracksList[currentTrackIndex].id);
    setTrackURL(require(`../assets/player/music/${currentTrackIndex + 1}.mp3`));
    setPlaying(true);
    const player = document.getElementById('player');
    player.src = trackURL;
    player.preload = true;
    player.autoplay = true;
    player.loop = true;
    if (playing) {
      player.play();
    } else {
      player.pause();
    }
  }
  

  const renderCover = () => {
    if (!playing) {
      return <img className="img-cover-default" src={require(`../assets/player/covers/default.gif`)} alt="" />
    } else {
      return <img className="img-cover" src={require(`../assets/player/covers/${currentTrackIndex + 1}.gif`)} alt="" />
    }
  }


  return (
    <>
      <Container>
        <Row>
          <Col className="play-list" xs={{ span: 12, order: 2 }} lg={{ span: 4, order: 1 }}>
            <p className="your-rythm ">WHAT'S YOUR RYTHM?</p>
            <br />
            {DB.map((track, index) => (
              <div
                key={track.id}
                index={index}
                className={`song ${track.id === trackID ? "selected" : ""}`}
                id={track.id === trackID ? "activeTrack" : ""}
                onClick={(ev) => selectThisTrack(ev, track.id)}
              >
                <p>{track.title}</p>
              </div>
            ))}
          </Col>
          <Col xs={{ span: 12, order: 1 }} lg={{ span: 8, order: 2 }}>

            <div className="song-cover">
              {
                renderCover()
              }
            </div>

          </Col>
        </Row>
      </Container>

    </>
  );
};

export default Player;
```

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is here:

```
const player = document.getElementById('player');
    const onPlayPauseClickHandler = (event) => {
        setPlaying(!playing);
        if (!playing) {
            player.play();
        } else {
            player.pause();
        }
    }
```

React doesn't update right after `set*` is called. Instead, you have to use `useEffect` to do play/pause.

Remove

```
if (!playing) {
    player.play();
} else {
    player.pause();
}
```

and use it in `useEffect`.

```
useEffect(() => {
    !playing ? player.play() : player.pause();
}, [playing]);
```

**EDIT**

Place the `useEffect` here:

```
const App = () => {
    const [currentTrackIndex, setCurrentTrackIndex] = useState(null);
    const [trackURL, setTrackURL] = useState('');
    const [playing, setPlaying] = useState(false);

    const callbackFunction = (currentTrackIndex, trackURL, playing) => {
        setCurrentTrackIndex(currentTrackIndex);
        setTrackURL(trackURL);
        setPlaying(playing);
    };

    const player = document.getElementById('player');
    const onPlayPauseClickHandler = (event) => {
        setPlaying(!playing);
    }
    const renderPlayBtn = () => {
        if (currentTrackIndex == null) {
            return;
        } else {
            return <div className="play-btn">
                <p onClick={onPlayPauseClickHandler} className={`play ${playing ? "red-bg" : "blue-bg"}`}>
                    {playing ? "SOUND OFF" : "SOUND ON"}
                </p>
            </div>
        }
    }

    // PLACE IT HERE
    useEffect(() => {
        !playing ? player.play() : player.pause();
    }, [playing]);

    return (
        <>
            <Router>
                <ScrollToTop />
                <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/'}`} >
                        <Home parentCallback={callbackFunction} player={player}/>
                    </Route>
                    <Route
                        path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/projects'}`}
                        component={Projects}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL}/project/:projectId`}
                        component={ProjectPage}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/team'}`}
                        component={Team}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/terms'}`}
                        component={TermsOfUse}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/privacy'}`}
                        component={PrivacyPolicy}
                    />
                    <Route
                        path={`${process.env.PUBLIC_URL + '/cookies'}`}
                        component={Cookies}
                    />
                    <Route exact component={Error} />
                </Switch>
            </Router>
            <audio id="player" src={trackURL} type="audio/mpeg"></audio>
            {
                renderPlayBtn()
            }
        </>
    );
};

export default App;
```

Comment: I can't call useEffect there  `React Hook "useEffect" is called in function "onPlayPauseClickHandler" which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function`  and the button works on other pages. I think it's a conflict between  app.js and the musicPlayer but I dont know where..

Comment: @DavidMuresan I have pointed in the solution where to put the ```useEffect```. Check it

Comment: it still does not work, "Cannot read property 'play' of null"

Comment: @DavidMuresan which line gives that error?

Comment: it's this line `!playing ? player.play() : player.pause();` from your edit in App.js. I tried to declate player in useEffect but it's not working